# Isn't this article in wikipedia wrong? (Multilinear form)

Tags: abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form

It says "The exceptional case of characteristic $2$ does not share this property." at last lines.

However, isn't it false?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M,N$ be $R$-modules and $\phi$ be an **alternating** multilinear map $M^n\rightarrow N$.

Then,

\begin{align}
0 &= \phi(...,x+y,...,x+y,...)\\
&=\phi(...,x,...,x,...)+\phi(...,x,...,y,...)+\phi(...,y,...,x,...)+\phi(...,y,...,y,...).
\end{align}

Hence, $\phi(...,x,...,y,...)=-\phi(...,y,...,x,...)$.

This argument does not use the property of characteristic at all. Isn't the line in wikipedia wrong?

Of course, the converse of this argument must assume the characteristic $\neq 2$, but I think this direction is not the case..

Comment: Why is $\phi(x, \dots, x) = 0$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese That is the definition of "alternating" in wikipedia..

Comment: You are right, there is no problem with that conclusion even in characteristic 2, and the specified wording in this wikia is misleading if not mistaken.

Comment: on page 350 of Jacobson's Basic Algebra I he says there is a distinction between alternate and skew-symmetric. In particular, to show skew-symmetric implies alternate he notes: $b(x,x)=-b(x,x)$ implies $2b(x,x)=0$( which fails to prove $b(x,x)=0$ in the characteristic two case). Nevermind, I see you appreciate this point already and Jacobson agrees with your conclusion about the other direction.